# Create a VSTS wiql file using VSTS APi

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

There are APIs to query using an existing wiq file.

I want my app to create actual wiq files in a shared folder - which can be accessed outside my app too. But I cannot find any API to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "can be accessed outside my app"? Are you saying you want to be able to access the **query results**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an API, see [Create a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/queries/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1#create_a_query) in the REST API.

The POST body should contains the WIQL Query and the name for it.

```
{
  "name": "All Bugs",
  "wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

To invoke the REST API, I suggest you to use a Microsoft library instead of writing all the code yourself, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries.

Answer (score 1):

What's that mean for `wiql files` here?

WIQL is [`Work Item Query Language`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=vsts), if you mean create a query with WIQL and save the query as a file, then no any API to do that, however you can try below steps:

1. Create a query with the `Query Editor`, save the query.
2. Open the query in Visual Studio --> `Edit Query`
3. `File` -> `Save {Query}[Editor] as...`

Then you can open and edit the saved `*.wiq` file with text editor, then save/copy to a shared folder...

Reference below articles:

- [Export a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#export-a-query)
- [Quickly generate Work Item Query for use in the TFS API](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-generate-work-item-query-for-tfs-api/)

[image]